# NoReverseMatch at /videos/list/ Reverse for 'list_videos' not found. 'list_videos' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Well I am trying to create a Playlist quite similar with YouTube. But the Playlist can only create by superuser from admin panel and other user can only see that playlist and the videos within the playlist. When I thought that I am done than suddenly this error occured. I don't know where I am making mistake. Please help me to fix this problem.

videos/models.py

```
class VideosList(models.Model):

    list_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    list_cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='list cover', height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None,blank =True)
    create_date = models.DateField(default = timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.list_title

class VideosModel(models.Model):

    
    videos_lists = models.ForeignKey(VideosList,on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    video_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    video_url = models.URLField(max_length=1200)
    video_discription = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateField(default = timezone.now)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.video_title
```

videos/views.py

```
class VideosListView(ListView):
    model = VideosList
    context_object_name = 'videos_lists'  
    template_name = "videos/videos_lists.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return VideosList.objects.filter(create_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-create_date')





class VideosModelListView(ListView):
    model = VideosModel
    template_name = "videos/list_videos.html"
    context_object_name = 'videos_list'  

    def get_queryset(self,*args, **kwargs):
        videoslist = get_object_or_404(VideosList, list_title=self.kwargs.get('list_title'))
        return VideosModel.objects.filter(videos_lists=videoslist).order_by('-create_date')
```

videos/urls.py

```
app_name = 'videos'

urlpatterns = [
    path('list/',views.VideosListView.as_view(),name ='videos_playlist'),
    path('list/<str:list_title>/',views.VideosModelListView.as_view(),name ='list_videos'),
]
```

videos/videos_list.html

```
{% extends 'pages/videos.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% for all_lists in videos_lists %}
<p style='text-align:center'><img src="{{ all_lists.list_cover.url }}" alt="No cover" height="450px" width="550px" ></p>
#This h2 line generating error and I dont know how to fix it.
<h2 style='text-align:center'>Title :<a href="{% url 'list_videos' all_lists.videos_lists.list_title %}"> {{ all_lists.list_title }}</a></h2> 

        <div class="date">
            <p style='text-align:center'>
                Published on: {{ all_lists.create_date|date:"D M Y" }}
            </p>
         </div> 
<br></br>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

videos/list_videos.html

```
{% extends 'pages/videos.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1 style='text-align:center'>List : {{ view.kwargs.list_title }}</h1>
{% for all_videos in videos_list %}
<h2 style='text-align:center'>{{ all_videos.videos_lists }}</h2>
<p style ='text-align:center'>
<object style="height: 390px; width: 640px"><param name="movie" value=""><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><embed src="{{all_videos.video_url}}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="390"></object>
</p>
<p style ='text-align:center'>
Discription :{{all_videos.discription}}
</p>
        <div class="date">
            <p style='text-align:center'>
                Published on: {{ all_videos.create_date|date:"D M Y" }}
            </p>
         </div> 
<br></br>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your videos/videos_list.html update `<a>` tag like this,

```
<a href="{% url 'videos:list_videos' all_lists.videos_lists.list_title %}"> {{ all_lists.list_title }}</a>
```

Comment: I just update that and now I get the following error : NoReverseMatch at /videos/list/
Reverse for 'list_videos' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['videos/list/(?P<list_title>[^/]+)/$']

Comment: there's something wrong with this parameter `all_lists.videos_lists.list_title` in the `<a>` tag. Debug that by printing the value in console.

Comment: I tried but it shows me following error in shell :AttributeError: 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'list_title'

Comment: I actually dont know how to fix this. thats why i am asking for help.

Comment: That parameter should be `all_lists.list_title` not `all_lists.videos_lists.list_title`